# How can I handle this error in closure right in rust

Tags: rust

I have a rust function which uses regex to replace string matching a certain rule. I am using the rust `regex` library, but I can't figure out how to handle `error` when using the closure.
My app has a custom error handler and I want to map the error returned in this function

```rust
pub fn override_from_env(content: &mut String) -> Result<()> {
  *content = regex!(r"\B\$\{([A-Z0-9_]*?)\}")
    .replace_all(&content, |captures: &Captures| {
      let key = captures.get(1).unwrap().as_str();
      match ::std::env::var(key) {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(e) => {
          Error::EnvVarError(e);
          String::from("") // this is not necessary, I want to return the error outside the closure here
        }
      }
    })
    .into_owned();

  Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Ohh yeah something like this could work expect that I actually didn't want the replace to continue as soon as it encounters an error...

Comment: Please add answers as answers, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to refactor this using `capture_iter`

```rust
pub fn transform_from_env(template: &mut String) -> Result<String> {
  let mut content = String::new();
  let mut last = 0;
  let re = regex!(r"\B\$\{([A-Z0-9_]*?)\}");

  for cap in re.captures_iter(&template) {
    let range = cap.get(0).unwrap();
    content.push_str(&template[last..range.start()]);
    let key = cap.get(1).unwrap().as_str();
    ::std::env::var(key).map(|val| {
      content.push_str(&val);
    })?;
    last = range.end();
  }

  if content.len() == 0 && template.len() > 0 {
    content = template.to_string();
  }

  Ok(content)
}
```